# Extracting a variable in a try-catch block

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal-7, return-value

I have a function:

```
function collect_user_balance() {
    userBalance = 0;
    try {
        var args = {
            param: 'name';
        };
        mymodule_get_service({
            data: JSON.stringify(args),
            success: function (result) {
                userBalance = result['0']; //here i am getting the balance as userBalance through service//
            }
        });
    } catch (error) {
        mymodule_error(error)
    }
}
```

The requirement is that to get the user balance, userBalance in other functions.

Something like

```
var getbal = collect_user_balance();
```

I am really new to JavaScript and this kind of things. How can I do this?

Comment: You should use `var` to declare `userBalance`; otherwise, you're making a global variable.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `mymodule_get_service` is an asynchronous function. That means that it lets code after it run even though itself hasn't completed yet. When it completes, it executes the `success` function. But by the time it completes, `collect_user_balance` has finished and this line:

```
var getbal = collect_user_balance();
```

Has already happened too early. To fix it, you need to let `collect_user_balance()` accept a callback function that will be called to let the caller know when information is ready. This might be hard to integrate, but that's what happens when you mix synchronous and asynchronous code. An example:

```
function collect_user_balance (callback) {
    try {
        var args = {
            param: 'name';
        };
        mymodule_get_service({
            data: JSON.stringify(args),
            success: function (result) {
                callback(result['0']); //here i am getting the balance as userBalance through service
            }
        });
    } catch (error) {
        mymodule_error(error)
    }
}
```

Then, you would call it like this:

```
collect_user_balance(function (userBalance) {
    // do useful stuff with userBalance
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function collect_user_balance() {
    userBalance = 0;
    try {
        var args = {
            param: 'name';
        };
        mymodule_get_service({
            data: JSON.stringify(args),
            success: function (result) {
                userBalance = result['0']; //here i am getting the balance as userBalance through service//
            }
        });
    } catch (error) {
        mymodule_error(error)
    }

    return userBalance;
}
```

You only need to return the var value: **return userbalance;**

I hope this can help you

Answer (score 0):

Better to avoid such a call as it may damage the performance of your app waiting for the service.

if you still need such a function you need to make the function synchronous .
in jquery  while calling ajax .we can use a property called async which is by default true and must be set false to make the call sync  .

```
function collect_user_balance() {
    userBalance = 0;
    try {
        var args = {
        param: 'name';
        };

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "http://someurl.com/ws",
        data: JSON.stringify(args),
        success: function(data) {
             userBalance = (int)data;
        },
        async:false
        });
    } 
    catch (error) {
        mymodule_error(error)
    }
    return userBalance ;
}
```

Please Note i have not tested the code .Let me know if it has some error